# Caching in ASP.NET for large objects

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application. It uses class System.Web.Caching.Cache to cache (for several minutes) some objects.
This solution works OK; but sometimes (not often) the objects may be too large to fit into memory.
Is there a simple solution to set, say, some ‘swap mode’ for the System.Web.Caching.Cache? I mean – to not try to keep such object in memory, but to save it on disk. Or some other simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your own implementation of an [OutPutCacheProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.outputcacheprovider.aspx) to work like you want. Gal Ratner has [an example of a Cache Provider](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/06/06/write-your-own-outputcacheprovider.aspx) that stores objects on disk as zip files, for instance. Or there is [this article on CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94803/ASP-NET-Output-Cache-Provider) about it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should cache those objects, but one solution could be to write a wrapper around `System.Web.Caching.Cache`. When you add objects to it have an option to serialize them to disk. Getting back the objects from disk will be considerably slower than from the cache.